# One file to rule them all

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have about 10 forms on my website and I want to handle their data with a single php file (submit.php). So `action="./submit.php"` in all my forms.

Today I use GET to call different functions in that php file when i submit my forms, example `action="./submit.php?func=user"`. That way the submit.php knows what form was submitted. Naturally the forms uses POST as method.

Is this a bad way to go about? Should I have one .php file for each form? Is there a better way?

Comment: you can try `isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Complexity:

It can get really hairy really fast -- the more forms, the more fun.

That is the reason why most frameworks use one file per class and why most frameworks supply a form class to build / validate / process forms.

It obviously adds to the folder structure complexity and the number of files. It sometimes generates files only for convention purposes -- such as a file which only contains an empty new class which extends some other class.

This is a price most pay for "nice and clean structures". It's readable, it's standardized(ish), it's common and familiar to other developers.

### Security:

If you allow your code to run **any** function based on the user supplied data than you have a possible security breach. If you also take your arguments from the user supplied data then you're basically providing an open unsecured RPC server.

I could run `?func=unlink&param[0]=/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` boom, your server's down on next restart.

If you check the function name in `$_GET['func']` against a restricted list of allowed functions such as checking `in_array($_GET['func'], array('functionOne', 'functionTwo'))`. Then you're safe.

### Maintenance:

Working MVC day-in and day out can skew ones perception of what is "necessary". I'd say that it's "necessary" for you to learn MVC and write 20 files to do the same thing you'll accomplish with this one file.

On the other hand I've been in your exact spot on various legacy projects and I've said "meh, MVC isn't always necessary, I'll just patch and fix this thing because it's faster at the moment". And I did, I patched and fixed stuff, 20-30 times until the entire effort of writing 20 files in the first place didn't seem that much.

So on a maintenance scale MVC is a big initial investment with a big return of investment whenever you revisit that project.

### Answer:

In my opinion structure helps, break thos forms into multiple files. Even if you submit the request to "submit.php" and "submit.php" includes the appropriate file for each form based on the `$_GET` parameters.

Furthermore, use classes and polymorphism. This will help you include files automatically based on the classes you're trying to use (read about [__autoload()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) and about autoloading standards [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/), [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/))

With polymorphism your "submit.php" might look as simple as the following:

```
// submit.php

/* some bootstrapping code you use to get your project settings up and running */
require_once('../bootstrap.php'); 

if(!empty($_GET['form']) and !empty($_GET['params'])) {
    $formClass = $_GET['form'];
    $params = $_GET['params'];
    if(class_exists($formClass) and is_subclass_of($formclass, 'FormInterface')) {
        $form = new $formClass;
        if($errors = $form->validate($params)) {
            $message = $form->process($params);
            if($message === '') {
                echo($message);
            }
        }
        else {
            echo('<ul class="errors">');
            foreach($errors as $error) {
                echo('<li>'.$error.'</li>');
            }
            echo('</ul>');

            /* reprinting the form to allow the user to try again */
            echo $form->toHtml();
        }
    }
    else {
        /* hack attempt? */
        echo("The form you are submitting doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

You don't know (or need to know) what class `$formClass` is. The autoloader knows in which folder the class is supposed to be and what filename it should have. After it being incldued by the autoloader you can just start using it for example to check if the class implements all of the functions of the `FormInterface` interface, if it does then it's safe to go ahead and try to validate the form using that class.

Comment: Great answer! I will convert to the MVC way, just after I try "?func=unlink&param[0]=/etc/apache2/sites-available/default"

Comment: The URL might not work -- it's just an example. I don't know what code you have back there, how you handle the parameters etc.. Also file permissions might not allow Apache2/PHP to delete files from `/etc/`. Also the server might be Windows not Linux... bla bla bla... and so on and so forth.

Comment: Also if it does work be prepared with a backed up copy of that file.

Comment: Looking back at my old questions your reply makes so much more sense. I really enjoy working with routing and MVC, keeping projects readable and organised is the way to go. Thanks for taking your time with this answer.

Comment: Well, was your initial setup an easily hackable RPC server or not?

Comment: No it wasn't, it was just an ugly way of handling form-data. It was my first php project and I wasn't familiar with MVC. I checked what form was submitted depending on func with a switch and ran different functions accordingly.

Comment: That switch fixed the security issue. On one of my first projects I think you could do literally any attack vector: sql injections, xss injections, remote code execution, arbitrary code execution, malicious uploads, you name it.

Comment: Best one I've seen is only checking if the client is logged in inside index, but other pages had no auth. You could just go to /page2. Everyone has atleast one old project with sql injection, but remote code execution is a nice touch. SSH with root toor and chmod 777 are also classics.

Answer (score 2):

Patrick!

In order to differentiate between forms you should try adding something like a namespace.
In your HTML you will have something similar to this:

> <form action="/submit.php" method="POST" name="myform1">
>      <input type="text" name="myform1[my_super_cool_text]" />
>   or
>      <input type="text" name="myform1[]" />
>   </form>

and so on for each form you have on that page.

In PHP you will retrieve each form by it's name like this:

> <?php
>     $myForm1 = $_POST['myform1'];
>    ....

That's it pretty much it.

Hope it helps, 
Denis Rendler

Comment: Thanks, that's another way to do this that i didn't know about.

Comment: Patrick, although this is the way to handle multiple forms in one HTML page, you should really consider Mihai Stancu's answer and learn a bit about the MVC and the way to separate concerns. I will help you very much in later projects. 
Also, thanks for the vote up. :)